# How include a php file of other directory's php file (back located directory file)?

Tags: php

you can see to different file address (1) and (2), i want to include header.php in index.php, but show error, i have used normal code in index.php: . sorry not working.

(1) localhost/folder1/index.php
(2) localhost/folder2/header.php

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

In index.php you should put

```
<?php
include '../folder2/header.php';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

index.php:

```
<?php
include __DIR__ . "/../folder2/header.php";
?>
```

This will work too when index.php is executed with current directory is not the folder `localhost/folder1`